# How to calculate volume of a 3D object in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, 3d, postgis

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL and I'm trying to calculate the volume of a 3D object with the shape of a rectangle.

Here's the table with the values:

```
CREATE TABLE warehousethree(
 name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
 wid serial NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT warehousethree_pk PRIMARY KEY (wid));

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('warehousethree', 'location', '3785', 'POLYHEDRALSURFACE', 3)

INSERT INTO warehousethree (name, location, wid) 
values
('Helianthus Italy', ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYHEDRALSURFACE(((43450771 11890747 0,43450755 11892667 0,43449727 11892882 0,43449688 11890994 0,43450771 11890747 0)),((43450771 11890747 500,43450755 11892667 500,43449727 11892882 500,43449688 11890994 500,43450771 11890747 500)),((43450771 11890747 0,43450755 11892667 0,43450755 11892667 500,43450771 11890747 500,43450771 11890747 0)),((43450755 11892667 0,43449727 11892882 0,43449727 11892882 500,43450755 11892667 500, 43450755 11892667 0)),((43449727 11892882 0,43449688 11890994 0,43449688 11890994 500,43449727 11892882 500,43449727 11892882 0)),((43449688 11890994 0,43450771 11890747 0,43450771 11890747 500, 43449688 11890994 500, 43449688 11890994 0)))', 3785), 1)
```

So far I've tried to combine the ST_Volume with ST_MakeSolid to calculate the volume but I get an error saying there's a problem with the syntax at the bracket following ST_Volume. I've tried some other ones which returned errors saying the functions didn't exit. Here is my query:

```
SELECT name ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(location)) as ware_solid_vol
FROM warehousethree
```

Any ideas about the correct syntax for this query will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Both `ST_Volume` and `ST_MakeSolid` are provided by the `postgis_sfcgal` extension which is not necessarily installed by default with postgis. You need to install it by typing in the following command from your operating system shell.

```
psql -d mydatabase -c 'create extension postgis_sfcgal';
```

Once it has been installed on your database your query should change to

```
SELECT ST_Volume(ST_MakeSolid(location)) as ware_solid_vol
 FROM warehousethree
```

Note that I have rubbed out 'name' from the query.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that clarifies a lot! Can I just ask for some clarification on installing the extension? I put this line in the psql console but I keep getting a syntax error for -d. I've never used it before so I don't know if I'm inputting it correctly.

Comment: That psql command is to be run from the command line. If you are already in psql or a graphical client just do 'create extension postgis_sfcgal'; but you will need permissions.

Comment: I'm still waiting to get permission as I'm not the database manager. But it seems like it should work once that's sorted. Thank you for all the help!